# Adding a class to a DOM element inside a template created by an atmosphere package?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am currently utilizing Meteor, the materializecss atmosphere package, and the user-accounts:materialize atmosphere package. I am attempting to use materialize class-based styling to change the style of the user-accounts:materialize sign-in page, which is created by the {{>atForm}} template.

```
Template.atForm.onRendered( function(){
  var element = $(".at-form, .at-btn");
  element.addClass("grey lighten-2 grey-text text-darken-4");
});
```

This works great when the page is initially rendered. However, if I sign-in, then sign-out, the sign-in template is again presented but this time the onRendered() function isn't called and my styling is lost. How do I avoid that?

And is there a better way to influence elements inside a 3rd party template than calling onRendered()?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension to override the package template with your own. Much easier approach, I think.

@Kyll - I assummed that the README was enough of an example; here is how you could use it:

add the package to the meteor project with:

```
meteor add aldeed:template-extension
```

Add your new template

```
<template name="myTemplate">...</template>
```

In the startup code on the client side, override the template:

```
Template.myTemplate.replaces("originalTemplateName");
```

Comment: This answer contains little to no information except for the link. Can you please edit it to reflect your solution? For example, you could include a code demonstration.

Comment: If I'm understanding the intent of .replaces() it completely overwrites the original template. That is too invasive for what I've attempting to accomplish in this particular instance, considering I'm aiming to change the class of only one element generated by that template. It definitely is an option, but if I have to completely replace that template I might as well fork the useraccounts:materialize package and make my changes to the template directly. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that at-form has sub templates that change. You need to handle onRendered for each of them to make sure your class is applied to them all.